# Relative Layout messed up on Android 4.4.4

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout

I have a relatively simple relative layout with some buttons that gets messed up only on Android 4.4.4. Any ideas?

I ensured that the target sdk is set to 20, and tested it against API 19.

Can't think of anything that could cause this.

This is the messed up version: http://oi62.tinypic.com/2churgg.jpg

This is how it looks on 3 different Virtual Machines (API 17, 19) and several phones: http://oi60.tinypic.com/23rvm1w.jpg

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/allTagsButton"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/allPhotosButton"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:onClick="goToAllTags"
    android:text="All Tags" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/allPhotosButton"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
    android:onClick="goToAllPhotos"
    android:text="View Photos" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btchangepass"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/allPhotosButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rateSimilarityButton"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:onClick="changePassword"
    android:text="Change Pass"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/clusterButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/rateSimilarityButton"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:onClick="goToClustering"
    android:text="Cluster Photos" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/rateSimilarityButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/allPhotosButton"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:onClick="goToRateSimilarity"
    android:text="Rate Similarity" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/logout"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btchangepass"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btchangepass"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="logOut"
    android:text="Logout" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonAddPhotos"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/logout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btchangepass"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:onClick="addPhotos"
    android:text="Add Photos"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What does "messed up" mean? You may wish to upload screenshots somewhere and link to them from your question.

Comment: It says I need at least 10 reputation, so I linked to it here: http://oi62.tinypic.com/2churgg.jpg

Comment: Your layout file is incomplete, missing at least the closing `</RelativeLayout>` tag, and perhaps more (unclear to me). How are you using this layout? If you are inflating it in a `ListView`, as that screenshot suggests, are you doing so manually? If so, post the code where you are doing that inflation.

Comment: I'm sorry this is my first stackoverflow question.. The missing closing tag was just not displayed in the code block, I fixed it now. I am using this layout normally in the onCreate method of the activitiy: setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

Comment: That doesn't line up with the screenshot, though, as in the screenshot there's what looks like at least four copies of this layout, vertically stacked. You might want to use Hierarchy View to try to make sense of what you have.

Comment: This is how it is supposed to look: http://oi60.tinypic.com/23rvm1w.jpg
No copies or vertical stacks or anything.

Comment: That's why I suggest using Hierarchy View to determine if you are indeed getting multiple copies or if that is some artifact of another problem (e.g., strangeness with Host GPU mode enabled on an emulator). If you are getting multiple copies, that has nothing to do with the layout itself and everything to do with your Java code.

Comment: Here is the hierarchy view output: http://oi59.tinypic.com/2mq14oy.jpg

Comment: That looks normal and does not match the screenshot. Assuming the wireframe diagram in Hierarchy View also matches your expected output, then the problem lies in your 4.4.4 environment. If that's the IDE preview, ignore it. If that's an emulator, turn off Host GPU mode and see if that helps.

Comment: This screenshot is from an actual phone, a Nexus 5, not an emulator or IDE preview.

Comment: Then I have no explanation for your symptoms, sorry.

Comment: nothing seems wrong, i have tested on 4.4.4 google nexus

Answer (score 0):

use @+id/ only for first time you use that id, replace unnecessary @+id/ with @id/. after this change your layout should work fine.